# Android: How to display a fullscreen layer (hide onClick)?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to pop up a layer in fullscreen mode (overlays the whole desktop) and hide on click.

I'm new in Android developing and looking for something like this (pseudocode):

```
$('#layer').on('click', function() {
    this.hide();
});

<div id="layer" class="fullscreen">I'm a annoying layer, click me!</div>
```

Does anyone have a solution, code snippet, tutorial or some keywords to google for? I follow some basic tutorials right now and would like to know in which direction I've to focus.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to do this in a native application using Java? Or in a web app using html/js (jquery)?

Comment: @FoamGuy Native, using Java - unfortunately.

Comment: I don't see why that is unfortunate. But anyway. What do you have so far? Do you already have an application with an Activity?

Comment: Because a web app would't be the problem. :) I've just a basic app, based on the official tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple activity that will close itself when the screen is touched.

**activity_popup.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
       android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**PopupActivity.java**

```
public class PopupActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.your.package.name.PopupActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thats almost what I wanted, thanks! The popup works but it's not "real" fullscreen. Is it possible to change `match_parent` to something like `device_width` and `device_height`?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "real" fullscreen. If you are referring to the notification bar, and the title bar though you can get rid of those by adding Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen to the activity in your manifest.xml file. See my edit for example.

Comment: Great, thats what I meant. Sorry, for my vague question and thanks a lot!